# jQuery Ui datepicker only showing on first click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jQuery UI datepicker and basically on page load the first time I click on the input field the datepicker shows but if I click on it again nothing happens.

Can Anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#delDate').datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: 0 
    });
});

<input type="text" name="delDate" id="delDate" value="" />
```

**Page in question its on step 4 if you click an image on the first page then just keep pressing next**
http://www.xperience-web.com/heywood/?page_id=32

Comment: Sorry Was an error putting the question up

Comment: There is no close tag of the anonymous function.

Comment: This should work. Do you have some other code that calls `unbind("click")` or `off("click")` on that `<input>` element?

Comment: Nope no errors in console @roasted

Comment: Nope nothing @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: @RayShih What do you mean no close tag on the anonymous function.

Comment: It should be:

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#delDate').datepicker({ 
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            minDate: 0 
        });
});

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to the page in question? It'll be something like invalid code putting the page into quirks mode or the same id being used multiple times.

Comment: Oh, I mean the close parenthesis "})"

Comment: @MarkLancaster first thing comes to my mind is there can be an `event.preventDefault()` somewhere that causes this or if you adding this dynamically add this code after dynamic insertion.

Comment: @scoota269 link added in original post

Comment: I wonder if its one of the other plugins causing issues, jquery-validate maybe? Have you tried stripping everything else out and adding them back in one by one?

Comment: Not yet no as there is quite a lot to strip back with it being a big project. I think thats the next option though. Thank you @scoota269

Comment: @BerkerYüceer Thank you for the reply I did a search for prevent default on the entire project and no such luck. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to change 0 to null

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Comment: Thank you for the reply I coppied the code from the Ui website. I've tried changing it to null and still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qZ6b5/

The lack of style in the demo is because only the jquery ui script is referenced, and not the css file.

html:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="delDate" id="delDate" value="" />​
```

js:

```
$('#delDate').datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: 0 
    });​
```

Comment: you know there is an Add Resources button at the panel right?

Comment: @BerkerYüceer yes this is what I used to add the abouve code.

Answer (score 0):

Your document ready code doesn't seems to be in correct format. Write it like this and try again:

```
$(function() {
    $('#delDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, But I have just tried this and no joy.

Comment: Ok, went to you site and found some error like `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` after the first click on date..

Comment: Thank you Palash, I've managed to fix this now. I used another jQuery date picker and it worked first time. Thank you to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After spending quite a long time trying to fix this I ended up using a different date picker and it worked first time.